# How to tell Yarn to ignore proxy env vars?

Tags: proxy, yarnpkg

I'm running Linux and have set proxy env vars under `/etc/environment` which I guess Yarn uses to connect to the npm repository.  For some reason, the proxy dies these days and Yarn keeps trying to connect to the proxy without giving me any chance of telling it what to do. I have set `export http_proxy=""` and `export https_proxy=""` with no luck.  How do I tell Yarn to **hey go direct**.

Edit: Surprisingly Yarn doesn't respect to anything I set.

- passing `--proxy ""` `--https-proxy ""` doesn't work.
- setting another proxy env doesn't work.

It seems Yarn has a severe problem in respecting user configuration. Installing npm right now.

Anyway, shouldn't it at least prompt me what I should do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case I would use the unset Unix command to clear those proxy variables

`unset http_proxy; unset https_proxy`

What I have done, because [yarn also doesn't respect the no_proxy variable](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/5048), and I need that part of it, is to essentially create a wrapper shell script over yarn that I use.

~/bin/my_yarn.sh

```
unset http_proxy; unset https_proxy; yarn $1
```

Then do `~/bin/my_yarn.sh install` to install, or whatever.